# ASp.Net MVC 4 how to call SSRS report

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have to call SSRS report from Asp.net MVC 4 project (.net framework 4.5).

I have added one Asp.net web form (aspx) in Asp.net MVC project. 
In Asp.net Web form i have added "Report Viewer" control.

I got error as "El control web del visor de informes requiere un System.Web.UI.ScriptManager en el formulario web."

could you please let me know what is the error. I

Answer (score 1):

First ensure that, U have added Script manager on page?
U have to add `ScriptManager` first. Then its one property is there named `EnablePartialRendering` set this to false.
 `ReportViwer` required `ScriptManager` to be added.
Your `ScriptManager` and `ReportViewer` should be in form like this

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
   <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" AsyncRendering="False">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</form>
```